# How to change data-icon attribute as the result of xmlHTTPRequest?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mobile

I am trying to change the data-icon of a given row in a listview. The jquery attr() function and the javascript setAttribute() function are both not working.

```
 <script>
    function increment(id) {
        var row = "row" + id;
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
          document.getElementById("issue"+id+"Upvote").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        $(row).attr("data-icon", "arrow-d");

        }
      }
      xmlhttp.open("GET","increment.php?q="+id,true);
      xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>


    //Fetching from your database table.
    $query = "SELECT * FROM $usertable";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if ($result) {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $issue = $row["issueName"];
            $upvotes = $row["upvotes"];
            $id = $row["issueID"];
            echo "<li data-icon=\"arrow-u\" id=\"row".$id . "\"> <a href=\"point.php\">".$issue ."</a><a href=\"javascript:increment(".$id.");\"></a> <span id=\"issue".$id."Upvote\" class=\"ui-li-count\">" .$upvotes."</span></li>";

        }
    }
```

Comment: I think that you have an error in your DOM selector, could you poste your HTML?

Comment: not much other relevant html. I have changed the error in the selector, but it's still not working..any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You set row as

```
var row = "row" + id;
```

But your selector is

```
$(row)
```

Making it, for example

```
$('row1')
```

If it's an ID, it should be

```
$('#'+row)
```

**EDIT** Once you have your selector working, to change the icon in jquery mobile, use `buttonMarkup`.

```
$('#'+row).buttonMarkup({ icon: "star" });
```

Comment: changed that error, but it's still not working..other possible issues?

Comment: Assuming your selector is correct, and your request is succesful, it should work fine. Here is a [JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/papic/1/edit?js,console,output)

Comment: It looks like you're using jQuery mobile and are trying to change the icon by changing the data attribute. That wont work... You need to use `buttonMarkup`. View updated answer.

Comment: for some reason, that doesn't work either. very strange. thank you for the help, but do you have any other ideas? I provided the only code that could be relevant. much appreciated

Comment: Try simply adding a `console.log('test')` inside the request success block to ensure the request is successful first. Assuming that block of is executing, I am 100% positive my code works. You can test it by going [here](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.1.1/docs/buttons/buttons-icons.html) and typing `$('.content-primary').find('a:first').buttonMarkup({ icon: "star" });` in the console. Watch the first button's icon change to a star.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to change html before inserting into dom:

```
var toInsert = $( xmlhttp.responseText );
toInsert.attr("data-icon", "arrow-d");
$("#issue"+id+"Upvote").html().append( toInsert );
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!         $(row.toString()).find('.ui-icon').removeClass('ui-icon-custom').addClass('ui-icon-star'); Thanks